# Elasticsearch no node available (after power outage)

Tags: elasticsearch

Yesterday we had a power outage and were able to get all of our machines back online with the exception of one box.

When firing up our application we see the log

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class    [com.levelsbeyond.search.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchTransportClientProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:97)
at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.createMuleContext(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:169)
at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:98)
at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.contextInitialized(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and then consistently repeated we see

```
2014-09-19 11:35:19,200 WARN [org.elasticsearch.transport.netty] (elasticsearch[Dominic Fortune][transport_client_worker][T#5]{New I/O worker #5}) - <[Dominic Fortune] Message not fully read (response) for [12] handler future(org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler$1@625badaa), error [true], resetting>
```

Everything was working perfectly fine until the power outage. This is a single node in the cluster and it is running on the same machine as the java application (centos 6.5) so I know this isn't the same issue you keep finding on SO and on google that states this issue is caused by different version of elasticsearch and/or Java.

Does anyone no how to recover from this and get back up and running?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that when the power went out, a restart triggered an auto update of elasticsearch and the upgraded version didn't support the transport drivers in use.